# Check UK visit visa status in Ukraine

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

I have applied for UK visit visa 3rd of Aug 2016 in Kiev, Ukraine.
Still I did not get any reply . Please advice me

Comment: What exactly is your question ?